# Dragula receive touch event from HammerJS?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, dragula

I would like to combine dragula with HammerJS in a way that dragging only happens in Dragula after a press event in HammerJS. With the current code the user has to lift his finger and touch again to the drag event to begin to happen.

Is there a way that the drag event happens after the long touch without lifting fingers?

Currently I am having a global variable called touch. As long as Touch is true, Dragula drag events are returned. I set HammerJS to make the touch variable false and then let the dragula touch event happen. The issue is that it needs the user to touch again the screen for the Dragula touch event to happen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dragula.min.css">
<style>
body div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
<div>Fourth</div>
<div>Fifth</div>

<script src="dragula.min.js"></script>
<script src="hammer.min.js"></script>
<script>
var touch = true;
var scrol;
var subjs = document.querySelectorAll("body div");
subjs.forEach(function (entry) {
    hammer = new Hammer(entry, {dragLockToAxis: true, dragBlockHorizontal: true}),
    hammer.on('press', function(e){
        touch = false;
        e.target.classList.add("dragging");
        document.querySelector('body div').addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            if (e.changedTouches[0].clientY < 80) {
                if (scrol == undefined) {
                    scrol = setInterval(view.pageScroll,100); 
                }
            } else if (e.changedTouches[0].clientY > 80 && e.changedTouches[0].clientY < (window.screen.height - 80)) {
                console.log(scrol)
                clearInterval(scrol);
                scrol = undefined;
            } else if (e.changedTouches[0].clientY > (window.screen.height - 80)) {
                if (scrol == undefined) {
                    scrol = setInterval(view.pageScrollDown,100); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
drake = dragula([document.querySelector('body')],{invalid: function (el, handle) {
    return touch; // don't prevent any drags from initiating by default
}}); 
drake.on("drop",function(el, target, source, sibling){
    clearInterval(scrol);
});
drake.on("dragend",function(el){
    touch = true;
    el.classList.remove('dragging')
});
var list = document.querySelector('body').children;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (touch == true) {
            drake.destroy();
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to initiate dragula touch event from HammerJS event?